# Using Auto-Layout with Frame Initializer

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am trying to implement a custom UISegmented Control into my program. Is there a way that I can use Auto Layout alongside CGRect (without having a ton of layout conflicts) or get rid of it altogether?
Below is the code I am using to create the specific instance of the segmented control. A frame initializer is required.

```
    let seg = YSSegmentedControl(
        frame: CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 0,
            height: 0),
        titles: [
            "First",
            "Second",
            "Third"
        ],
        action: {
            control, index in
            print ("segmented did pressed \(index)")
        })

    seg.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(seg)
}
```

}

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: Speaking for myself, when I use auto layout - which really anymore is "always" - I typically use an empty initializer when possible, and when a designated initializer requires a frame, `CGRect.zero`. In your case, I'd replace the explicit frame with that - it makes your intentions more clear. Then I'd give it a height/width layout anchors along with placement according to your needs.

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Unfortunately YSSegmentedControl wouldn't except an empty initializer, so I did have to go the CGRect.zero root. I had tried this before, but only included the positional anchors and not the height width anchors. After I added the height and width anchors, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You should use or frame layout constructor which is old style, or use constraints.
I dont believe that this class does not have standart YSSegmentedControl() initializer.